# Can I set directories to other than "js" and "jvm" using the Scalajs sbt plugin's cross-project?

Tags: sbt, scala.js

It appears that the sbt plugin for Scala.js has hard-coded paths of "jvm" and "js" for the cross-project subdirectories that contain code targeted for the server and client, respectively?

Am I missing something?  Is it possible to set those names in my Build.scala / build.sbt?

It appears not easily, since the CrossType abstract class declares jvmDir and jsDir functions to be final?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own `CrossType` and override the `projectDir` method:

```
class MyCrossType extends CrossType {
  def projectDir(crossBase: File, projectType: String): File = ???
    // your directory structure. pattern match on projectType,
    // if you want other names than js and jvm

  def sharedSrcDir(projectBase: File, conf: String): Option[File] = ???
    // Location of shared source directories (if you want one).
}
```

The `jvmDir` and the `jsDir` functions use the `projectDir` function internally. Therefore you can just use `MyCrossType` in some of the default `CrossType`'s stead and you are ready to go.

Comment: This is most likely obvious to experienced sbt users, but I am not sure: where should I define MyCrossType? In the build.sbt? How? When I try it naively, I get an sbt error parsing expression.

Comment: You'll have to do this in a scala file inside the project directory. E.g. `project/MyCrossType.scala`.

Comment: I found a way using anonymous class extending CrossType. Would you mind if I edit the answer to include the build.sbt example?